# I am getting function name in the form of a string from the backend i need to add it to onClick event of a button in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am getting function name in the form of a string from the backend i need to add it to onClick event of a button in react but getting error ReactJS: Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type string how can i add the string to onClick function

response object from backend :

```
[
{option : {onClickFunc : "getReleaseNotes"}}
],
```

React on front end

```
<div onClick={option.onClickFunc}>
</div>
```

error on click :

```
ReactJS: Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use eval

```
eval(option.onClickFunc)();
```

or add getReleaseNotes to an object and then get it with accessor

```
myFunctions[option.onClickFunc]();
```

Look at this post [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string) for more options.